# Set file creation date by reading modified date

Tags: finder, applescript

How can I set a file's creation date as the modified date?

e.g. File is made on Monday, edited on Tuesday. On Wednesday I want the date modified and date created to be set to Tuesday.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Apple OS are you running? OS X runs on top of Unix and Unix file systems do not track the creation date.

Comment: @garyjohn OS X has separate Created dates and Modified dates in the get info box... not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex: I guess I mean I have a limited understanding of OS X. From a little Googling it appears that OS X does track the creation time but that not all programs access it. Harry Fear: You might find this program useful: http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/ChangeFileDates/ChangeFileDates.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
f=test.txt
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")" "$f"
```

GetFileInfo and SetFile are part of the command line tools package, which can be downloaded from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) or from Xcode's preferences after installing it from the App Store.